# Trying to create a Linux OS drive that can be booted from any PC at any time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, boot, partition

I am currently trying to test multiple PC's (Same model and configuration) using Linux.

To put it as simply as possible, I want to fully install Linux on a USB thumbdrive and be able to boot it up using any PC.

I have tried to install both Mint and Ubuntu and neither of them allow me to boot to another machine.

The initial install drive boots without a problem, but once I try to boot from a fully installed Linux OS on a USB drive, the PC does not recognize bootable media.  It only boots on the PC I used to install the OS with.

I am not sure if I am partitioning it wrong, or if this simply isn't possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the resources available at https://www.pendrivelinux.com/?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI you must manually partition and create an ESP on external drive. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #55 or( #23 & #26)
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator If external bootable, just add an ESP using gparted to shrink any partition. Then copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu to new ESP. Update fstab in external with new UUID for ESP. Or totally reinstall grub.

Comment: See [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367302/how-to-make-a-portable-ubuntu-server) and links from it. The easiest alternative is to make a persistent live drive, but it is also possible to make an installed system and tweak it to boot other computers. Proprietary graphics and/or wifi drivers and computers needing it (for example with powerful nvidia cards and broadcom chips) limit the portability.

Comment: Look at the "lbu" utility under Alpine.  If you add your home directory to the persisted files, it might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)? It is a Linux distribution designed to be run off of a USB, personally, I have a live Tails USB that I have used on several different machines with no problems.

The installation process is very easy, and there is also the possibility of installing it onto a CD as well.

Hopefully this helps!